# Print a specific element on a page rather than the entire window

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to just print the contents of a specific HTML element rather than using window.print() to print the whole thing.   Something like this would be ideal

```
const elementToPrint = document.getElementById('elementToPrint');
elementToPrint.print();
```

I'm using Angular5 so there may be some package out there that is capable of this but I haven't found it

Comment: https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/ , https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/57

Comment: Is using CSS media queries an OK alternative or does it have to be through just JS?

Comment: I'll use CSS as a fallback.  I'd rather not pepper the CSS and HTML with more classes and rules but if that's the only way then it'll have to do.